# How to get values into Select Option Menu Using Ajax And PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 select box option, `item` and `part number`. I'm using php and ajax to get part number when I pick an item.

The issue is that, the html and php all work but for the ajax. Nothing populates in the `part number` select-box when an `item` is selected.

Here is my html and ajax side (`index.php`):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function fetch_select(val)
{
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'get_state.php',

     success: function (response) {
       document.getElementById("partno").innerHTML=response; 
     }
   });
}

</script>     
</head>    
<body>
<div id="select_box">
<form action="" method="post">
         Item: 
         <select name="item" id="item" onchange="fetch_select(this.value);">
           <option value="">select item</option>
           <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
           <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
        </select>
<br>
        Part: 
        <select name="partno" id="partno">
            <option value="">select part</option>
        </select>

</form>   
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php file (`get_state.php`):

```
<?php


//Connection to DB

//Select data from Table based on item selection
$query="SELECT partno FROM Table";          
    $params = array($_REQUEST['query']);
    $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

    if($results===false)
     { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }


     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
       echo "<option>".$row['partno']."</option>";
     }

     exit;

?>
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Add `console.log(response);`to your success function to see if returning the correct values.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct response ?

Comment: @JoseRodrigues, like this: 
       `success: function (response) {
       document.getElementById("partno").innerHTML=response;
       console.log(response); `

How do I access the log?

Comment: @Neelesh, It's not working that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: To debug JS, access the developper pannel by right clicking, selecting `Inspect element` then going to the `Console` tab. More infos here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging It will help you to see what's going on the client side (and see what are the `console.log` output)

Comment: Thanks @PiTiNiNjA.

Can you also help me debug my code?

Comment: Of course, update your post with what comes out from your console then we shall help you.

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA, It works fine in Chrome but not in IE.
Output:
`<option>12345678</option><option>14141414</option><option>15151515</option><option>87654321</option>`

Comment: What's not working? Getting the html through ajax or inserting the html in the dom?

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA, I figured it out after reviewing the error message the browser posted in the `console.log` output.

Thanks everyone!